# Embed stated not being sent to channel

Tags: discord.js

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
  ]
}); 
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
// All partials are loaded automatically
//const Discord = require('discord.js');



client.on('ready', async () => {
  console.log(`${client.user.username} is ready!`);
})
client.on('guildCreate', (g) => {
    const channel = g.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.type === 'GUILD_TEXT' && channel.permissionsFor(g.me).has('SEND_MESSAGES'))
    channel.send("Thanks for inviting flappy dank! Please run the command !run to get started!");
})
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
  if (message.content == '!testcmd') {
    const illla = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor(FF0000)
    .setTitle('Members Generator 2.0!')
    .setDescription('testing testing 123 123')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({ text: 'wow a footer'});
    message.channel.send(illla)
  }
})
```

I have tried the code above, when I run the command ‘!testcmd’, it does not output any embed. i have searched online for solutions, but none working. I expect and embed to be outputted, yet it doesn’t return any errors. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're using discord.js v14. There's a changes about sending Embeds

```js
const illla = new EmbedBuilder()
.setColor(FF0000)
.setTitle('Members Generator 2.0!')
.setDescription('testing testing 123 123')
.setTimestamp()
.setFooter({ text: 'wow a footer'});
message.channel.send(illla) //The Changes is in here
```

The comment line should change as:

```js
message.channel.send({embeds: [illla] });
```

[Click here to see more about EmbedBuilder](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-embed-constructor)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the issue.